# HTML Email not displaying correctly in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, html-email, outlook-2007

After a lot of time I put into researching. I still can't find an answer.

I have a HTML that is showing the wrong width in my tables. Here is a link to the html email: https://tagwebstore.com/email/tag-email-10percentmore.html and here is a screenshot of how it looks in Outlook 2007:

[image]

The main problem is the bottom area. The link of the html email displays it correctly. I have no idea what else to do from here. Here is my code for the bottom part I am having trouble with:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="625" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td height="23" colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/testimonial-top.png" width="573" height="36" style="display:block;" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f0d7c1" width="573"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="573">
                <tr>
                  <td width="28"></td>
                  <td style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:italic; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;" width="517"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:italic; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">We’ve been using TAG for a while and we love TAG &ndash; we love the products. When we bring the products to Oklahoma City, nobody else has the products. It’s a big plus here for our market area. I think it would be a great thing for people to get online and see what TAG can do for them.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="right">
                        <td height="40" valign="bottom" style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Sirron Brown, Marketing Director<br />
                          Excell Home Care and Hospice, Oklahoma</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  <td width="28"></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/testimonial-bottom.png" width="573" height="57" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!--Testimonial End--> 

  <!--Footer-->

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="625" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="575"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="295" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><a href="mailto:info@tagwebstore.com" style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">info@tagwebstore.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;866.232.6477</td>
            <td width="178" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;" valign="middle" align="right">Follow us on Twitter &amp; YouTube</td>
            <td valign="middle" width="102"><a href="https://twitter.com/TAGhomecaremktg"><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/twitter.png" width="49" height="17" border="0" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/TAGWebinars"><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/youtube.png" width="53" height="21" border="0" /></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!--Footer End-->
```

The width of the containing table is suppose to be 625px. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tested the full source code from the above URL in Litmus and it worked fine in Outlook 2003/2007/2013.

Comment: Really? My co-workers outlook 2007 is showing that its really out of whack. That's her screenshot she took for me. Would it be a computer thing also?

Comment: How are you testing it? If you're simply pasting the source code into Outlook and mailing it, Outlook may be corrupting the code. Litmus.com is fairly reliable. Granted, I haven't inspected the code, but since it renders ok in Litmus, I'd guess that there's a problem with how it's being tested.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of testing it in Outlook 2007 with Litmus: https://s3.amazonaws.com/resultcaptures/85abe448-c0e1-43e6-a58e-623dcf14fc41.fullpageon.png

Comment: I'm using Infusionsoft to run these email campaigns. I'm using Mailchimp's inbox inspector to see the preview, but it takes to long to process it in all the different mail clients.

Comment: Wow, that looks exactly what I need. Thanks for taking the time to test that for me!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### oh the joy of html emails

There are many rules you have to obey when dealing with HTML-based email, especially when you have exacting clients and pixel-perfect designs, and I am quite glad that I haven't had to work on such a project for at least two years now... The main reason for my utter dislike of the practice is primarily down to two email-clients. The first and all time worst being Lotus Notes 6.5.4 *(to be fair it's over 10 years old now.. but still!)*, and the all time second worst(s), they're not even the best at being bad, Outlook 2007 and 2010!

> Whoever thought it would be a good idea to use the Microsoft Word WYSIWYG HTML Engine to render HTML Emails in Outlook 2007 and 2010, must have been mad, lazy, lost or ever-so-slightly confused (delete as appropriate). It causes no end of rendering problems for developers, usually with random and inexplicable sizing calculations or padding problems.

*Taken from my blog http://blog.pebbl.co.uk/2011/06/collapsible-html-email-and-outlook.html*

Simply put, I do not envy you :)

I found the best way to help me out with my email troubles was to follow the following rules:

1. Never use `colspans` or `rowspans`.
2. Always set correct dimensions for your tables and cells.
3. Use spacer gifs rather than `&nbps;`.
4. Always specify correct image sizes and never scale images up or down.
5. Always add `style="display:block;"` to images.
6. Avoid using `divs`.
7. If you wish to colour links, put the styling on a span as a child inside the `a` tag.
8. Don't use italics.
9. Don't use BRs for layout, always use tables.
10. Use BRs in Text, not Ps (to avoid stange margin problems and paragraphing being completely ignored).

Because the sheer number of emails I used to get through ended up being ridiculous, I developed a script to help me with the work of checking dimensions and other possible pitfalls. If you're interested in using it you can find it here:

http://pastie.org/6250834

The script can be added as a usual script tag or enabled using GreaseMonkey or something similar (it was designed to work with Firefox but I see no reason why it shouldn't work elsewhere). Due to the way I used to build my emails, it will only enable itself if either the following conditions are met:

1. There is an outer wrapping table that has `width="100%"` set, used to centre the actual email content.
2. or... there is an outer element (a table or div) that has the `id="base"`.

I've passed your HTML through it and the image below is the resulting output, it makes more sense when you have the actual page because you can hover over each bordered item and it will give you a rough idea of what the problem is (either that or you can just inspect the element directly with Firebug or similar).

[image: ss of my email checker script]
[image: explanation of my email checker]

So from inspecting the above it seems you have a few problems that need to be fixed, I'd say the most important ones are to get rid of rowspans and colspans (these always cause problems in Outlook) and to make sure all your dimensions tally correctly. Once you've fixed these issues you might see a considerable improvement, but then again you might not, there are no certainties in the hazardous life of HTML email building...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate this. It's really helpful to see where the problems could be. I keep getting mixed answers about the <br>, because now outlook.com and hotmail.com will not support bottom margin for <p> anymore. That was announced last month. I also read that using spacer images isn't recommended either, mainly because of the download speed and spam score. HTML emails always give me a headache. I've been doing them for 3 years and I'm still learning about them. Thanks for the help, I will use this to help find the problem. :)

Comment: use br's, they are more consistent than p's.

Comment: @John good point in clarification, I was refering to using BRs in layout (not text formatting). I definitely should add don't use Ps.

Comment: @Alex no worries, hope something of the above was useful! Yeah, when I first started HTML email building I never realised how tricky it would be -- definitely more challenging keeping the numerous email clients happy than the web browsers now-a-days. It gets even more awkward if you start having to build responsive layouts :S

Comment: @AlexKittavong Oh & with regard to spacers, I'd stick with them personally if the client wants an exacting look & requires supporting old email clients. To get around spam issues just don't use loads of them, and make sure you have a few with different names. If your company is worried about added download size (hardly anything for spacers) then they need to accept their designs wont look so good in certain places. You have no choice but use a spacer if you want a space smaller than default text height and support old clients. It's not a key issue anyhow... you can definitely live with &nbsp;

Comment: What's the issue with italics?

Comment: It's helped a lot and with the answer below to also. Can't get to technical with html emails. Outlook is my worst nightmare. Thanks again for the help. I am still working on finding the issue, but I think the issue lies within the clients computer honestly. @MattCoughlin, it looked good in his outlook 2007. I hate to blame it on someone's computer, but it can definitely be a factor.

Comment: @AlexKittavong You don't really need to use spacer images in email. In Outlook, most spacing issues arise when the tables separate from forwarding the email (but that is another issue!). You can use padding on the `<td>` or create empty `<td>`'s with `&nbsp;`'s (like your example code) so that it doesn't collapse. For fake-padding above and below blocks of text use `&nbsp;<br>` and `<br>&nbsp;` respectively. If the `&nbsp` is missing at the start and end of the text block (where the table cell opens/closes) Outlook collapses it.  Just use `<br><br>` between paragraphs.

Comment: @MattCoughlin heh, ah that's more of a Lotus Notes 6.5.4 issue. It had many problems with certain fonts when rendering as italics, for one it had no anti-aliasing ability (some letters were truly illegible), and for two entire words would just vanish or get cut off :)

Comment: @pebbl I don't worry about older Lotus notes. From my tests they account for about 0.2% of subscribers, although each list is different. Also, col and rowspans have always worked great for me.

Comment: @John sure thing.. as I said at the start of my post I last built an email over 2 years ago, so I would expect things to move on. I just gave what my rules of thumb had been. Unfortunately when I was developing mails a large number of our client-base had that specific version of Lotus notes (ignoring the fact that the rest of the world had moved on). Rather annoying.

Comment: @pebbl I use .png's exclusively - take that Lotus Notes! Regarding colspans, when you forward an email from Outlook, it puts big gaps between tables thanks to Outlook wrapping `<p>` tags around them, so using bigger tables with more rows (and colspans in support) keeps the email in better shape.

Comment: +1 for never use rowspan or colspan - I just spent an hour trying to figure out a problem being caused by rowspan. Luckily I found this answer before I completely went insane.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Cheers, heh, yeah -- I had many-a-nightmare myself with rowspan oddities before I made it a rule; it's a shame though, they sure do make table layouts far easier! Glad my answer helped..

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped keep me from going insane too. FWIW, your rules gave me an idea: Since it is annoying to re-code to avoid  colspans, I wrapped each <tr> in a <table>. Tables always line up for me across email clients and I am testing with Litmus. This simplifies the code and allows me to remove colspans without rebuilding the HTML. I got weird behavior from Outlook because of colspans, but in the row after the colspan is used.

Comment: The pastie link in the answer is dead. If it could be updated that would be appreciated, otherwise your detailed suggestions are awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have it to hand right now, I'm away from my backups. But will see if I can find it and re-upload somewhere. Didn't realise pastie had gone.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for your top table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="625" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td height="23" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="575">

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/testimonial-top.png" width="575" height="36" style="display:block;" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#f0d7c1" width="575">
              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="28">
                  </td>
                  <td width="519" style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:italic; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:italic; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">We’ve been using TAG for a while and we love TAG &ndash; we love the products. When we bring the products to Oklahoma City, nobody else has the products. It’s a big plus here for our market area. I think it would be a great thing for people to get online and see what TAG can do for them.
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="right">
                        <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:11px; line-height:18px; color:#000000; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Sirron Brown, Marketing Director<br />
                          Excell Home Care and Hospice, Oklahoma</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td width="28">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/testimonial-bottom.png" width="575" height="57" style="display:block;" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

and this for your bottom:

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="625" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="575">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="280" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
              <a href="mailto:info@tagwebstore.com" style="color:#000001; text-decoration:none;">info@tagwebstore.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;866.232.6477
            </td>
            <td width="193" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;" valign="middle" align="right">
              Follow us on Twitter &amp; YouTube
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" width="49">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/TAGhomecaremktg"><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/twitter.png" width="49" height="17" border="0" style="display:block;" /></a>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" width="53">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/TAGWebinars"><img src="https://www.tagwebstore.com/email/youtube.png" width="53" height="21" border="0" style="display:block;" /></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Overall it was coded really well, just changed a few small things, not saying each was a must have, but IF it works you can reverse engineer the changes to find out what busted it. I haven't tested it, so hopefully this works...

Comment: yes this worked also. I am still trying to figure out why my widths were off when I calculated them correctly. I see that you used 100% as the width in the <td> you use as the container. Is it better to do it that way rather than to specify the exact width?

Comment: it would probably work both ways, but its one less place to have to set a width for something you want the same width as its parent.

Comment: True, less confusing that way.