# td element's width doesn't display correctly in HTML email

Tags: html-email, html-table

I'm having problem with displaying td.header width. It keeps taking up the width of p.event-detail.

Can someone help me fix the code so that td.header's width is 530px precisely.

```
<table bgcolor="#d8d8d8" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="15" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td class="header" width="530" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <h3>Wonderself - Kỹ năng xã hội cho các bé từ 3-6 tuổi</h3>
   </td>
   <td width="15" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="15" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td width="365">
     <p class="event-detail">Chương trình về EQ hàng đầu của Mỹ để giúp các bé từ 3-6 tuổi phát triển kỹ năng xã hội.</p>
     <img src="attend-button.jpg" alt="Attend this event">
   </td>
   <td width="15" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
   <td width="150">
     <img src="box.jpg" alt="normal event">
   </td>
   <td width="15" bgcolor="#d8d8d8">
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="10" bgcolor="#d8d8d8"></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<td class="header" width="530" bgcolor="#d8d8d8" colspan="2">
```

Comment: Sorry, change colspan number to 3 from 2

Comment: It works! Thanks. But I'm wonder if colspan is solidly supported in Outlook 2007 (according to the following discussion).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986147/html-email-not-displaying-correctly-in-outlook-2007

Have you encountered any issue with colspan in email design?

Comment: colspan is a standard HTML attribute of a TD element and has to be supported.

Comment: I've not had an issue with colspan in any mail client.

Comment: @Ace colspan works great, it is fully supported in all major email clients and a consistent method of laying out tables if you set them up properly and avoid [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697788/html-email-is-colspan-allowed/16964122#16964122) Outlook quirk